# Cannot Uninstall OpenDJ

Tags: java, openam, opendj

I am trying to install OpenDJ 2.6.0 in a "Windows Server 2008 Standard Without Hyper-V" environment.

It threw an error during installation when I tried to import an ldif file, but the install did finish.

The Windows Service was not created, so I'm trying to uninstall and try it again. But when I run "uninstall.bat --cli" from the command line, I get the error listed below.

I've tried a few other command line switch combos ("--cli -a", "--cli -f -n") without success.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
>   initialize class org.opends.server.util.Platform
>           at org.opends.admin.ads.util.ApplicationTrustManager.(ApplicationTrustManager.java:118)
>           at org.opends.guitools.uninstaller.UninstallUserData.(UninstallUserData.java:51)
>           at org.opends.guitools.uninstaller.Uninstaller.createUserData(Uninstaller.java:170)
>           at org.opends.quicksetup.Application.getUserData(Application.java:213)
>           at org.opends.quicksetup.Launcher.preExit(Launcher.java:390)
>           at org.opends.quicksetup.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:365)
>           at org.opends.guitools.uninstaller.UninstallLauncher.launch(UninstallLauncher.java:126)
>           at org.opends.guitools.uninstaller.UninstallLauncher.main(UninstallLauncher.java:79)

If I try to run setup.bat, I'm told that the Server "Has already been configured".

Answer (score 2):

If the windows service is not installed, then the easiest way to uninstall OpenDJ is just to delete it.
The error you are getting is kind of strange, as if OpenDJ jars have been messed up with.
What is the version of Java installed on your machine ? OpenDJ 2.6.0 was released before Java 8 was available and there is an incompatibility.

Comment: I can delete the files no problem, but I still need to install OpenDJ. And I get the "Has already been configured" message when I do. 

I have not touched the jars, but will delete and re-unzip to see if that makes a difference.

I have both Java 8 Update 45 and Java 7 Update 25 on this server, but a similar setup on my local system which installed/uninstalled cleanly several times.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the root cause was, but after rebooting the server, everything uninstalled and re-installed cleanly.

Comment: How did u reboot this ?? can you please explain...i wrongly configured.. how to reboot pls explain...@The Cline

Comment: By "reboot", I meant that I was able to physically restart the server.